# Do files have to be csv to differentiate between columns to plot a graph with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a line graph using data from a file that has several columns in it (16 in fact). I have bee trying to use the command

```
plot 'snr.dat' using 2:16 with lines
```

but I do not seem to be getting the result I would like.

I have attached an extract from the file I am using.

```
2014/10/30  0:00:28.847 00000 159.9   71.6  -12.51    .40   64.1   217.1  3    23.1     15        1   3511.  .055 -9.99  11.4
2014/10/30  0:00:28.847 00000 229.9  103.9  -12.51    .40   64.1   217.1  3    23.1     15        1   3511.  .055 -9.99  11.4
2014/10/30  0:00:28.847 00000 159.9   81.7  -12.51    .40   59.9    92.6  3    29.4     23        1   3511.  .055 -9.99  11.4
2014/10/30  0:00:28.847 00001 159.9   71.6  -12.51    .40   64.0   217.1  3    23.4     25        1   3508.  .055 -9.99  11.3
2014/10/30  0:00:28.847 00001 229.9  103.9  -12.51    .40   64.0   217.1  3    23.4     25        1   3508.  .055 -9.99  11.3
2014/10/30  0:00:28.847 00001 159.9   81.7  -12.51    .40   59.9    92.6  3    29.6     14        1   3508.  .055 -9.99  11.3
2014/10/30  0:01:30.114 00002 229.9   92.3    1.02   1.62   67.3   138.7  2    27.2     25        1   1746.  .138 -9.99   5.7
2014/10/30  0:01:30.114 00002 159.9   89.9    1.02   1.62   56.4    97.4  2    26.5     35        1   1746.  .138 -9.99   5.7
2014/10/30  0:02:30.504 00005  96.0   90.1  -25.64   1.18   20.3   120.5  1    17.2     45        1   2553.  .165 -9.99   8.7
2014/10/30  0:02:52.896 00007 102.0   91.5    2.23    .03   26.4   140.8  1    11.8     35        1  19393.  .098 -9.99  23.6
2014/10/30  0:02:52.890 00008 100.0   89.6    3.52    .57   26.5   139.9  1    10.9     35        1   4394.  .214 -9.99  13.0
2014/10/30  0:02:52.894 00009 104.0   93.3    2.39    .52   26.4   141.0  1    10.1     13        1   4376.  .110 -9.99  12.5
2014/10/30  0:03:20.093 0000B 106.0   84.5    5.30   2.01   37.4   202.2  1    25.8     45        1   2306.  .095 -9.99   7.8
2014/10/30  0:04:08.515 0000D 102.0   88.1   13.20   1.92   30.5   180.6  3    28.4     15        1   3200.  .061 -9.99   9.9
2014/10/30  0:04:08.515 0000D 102.0   99.4   13.20   1.92   12.9    68.6  3    26.1     45        1   3200.  .061 -9.99   9.9
2014/10/30  0:04:08.515 0000D 102.0   88.2   13.20   1.92   30.3   128.4  3    38.2     13        1   3200.  .061 -9.99   9.9
2014/10/30  0:04:12.642 0000E 108.0   91.9  -38.85    .20   31.9   222.0  1    23.8     15        1   9636.  .084 -9.99  20.2
2014/10/30  0:04:12.640 0000F 110.0   93.6  -38.17    .51   31.9   221.9  1    23.6     25        1   4974.  .086 -9.99  14.7
2014/10/30  0:04:40.580 0000G 201.9   93.0  -20.01    .41   63.4    38.1  1    24.7     15        1   2716.  .244 -9.99   9.3
```

I would like to have the time (that's in the second in the second column) on the x axis, and the snr values (that's in the 16th column) on the y axis with a line joining them.

Thanks for any help, and if you need any more info just ask please.

Answer (score 0):

Then you must tell gnuplot, that you want to plot time data on the x-axis with

```
set xdata time
```

and in which format the time should be parsed

```
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
```

So, a complete minimal script could be

```
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
plot 'snr.dat' using 2:17 with lines title 'SNR'
```

Comment: Excellent thank you, that has sorted it out. how do I join the points not add horizontal lines?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this part. The script as i showed it connects the points. Your 16th column (at least the part you posted) contains only -9.99 which gives a horizontal line.

Comment: Yep my mistake it is the last column I need which is the 17th column.